# Append/prepend to the container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, prepend

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div><div>...</div><a class="child" href="#">Example</a></div>..</div></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div><div>...</div><a class="child" href="#">Example</a></div>..</div></div>
</div>
.
.
.
<div class="container">
    <div><div>...</div><a class="child" href="#">Example</a></div>..</div></div>
</div>
```

And I have the following JavaScript script:

```
$('a.child').prependTo('div.container');
```

But this code, instead of making each `a` element prepended to their own container, makes *all* `a` elements prepended to *each* of the containers.
How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the `each` method:

```
$('a.child').each(function(){
  $(this).prependTo($(this).closest('.container'));
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X674N/)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers, they are all very similar and worked for me. This one seems to be the 'cleanest'

Answer (score 3):

Iterate over each `a.child`, and prepend it.

```
$('a.child').each(function ()
{
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.prependTo($this.closest('div.container'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/tRNUS

Answer (score 0):

`div.container` and `a.child` are acting as separate selectors. They aren't related.

You would have to loop over the `a.child` elements and select the parent element:

```
$('a.child').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);

  $this.parents('div.container').prepend($this);
});
```